# Prove vectors create a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $V$ be a vector space and $U,W,Z$ be it's subspaces where $V=Z \oplus U=Z\oplus W$.
We know that $\beta_1,...,\beta_k$ is a basis of $U$ and $\beta_i=\gamma_i+\delta_i$ where $\gamma_i \in Z$ and $\delta_i \in W$ for $i \in \{1,2,...,k \}$. Prove that $\delta_1,..,\delta_k$ is basis of $W$.

We know from the direct sum that $\dim U=\dim W=k$ but I don't know how tho show $\delta_1,..,\delta_k$ is linear independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\delta_i=\beta_i-\gamma_i$. It remains to prove that the family $(\delta_i)$ is linearly independent. Let $a_i\in\Bbb R$ such that

$$\sum_i a_i\delta_i=0\iff \sum_ia_i\beta_i=\sum_i a_i\gamma_i$$
hence since $U\cap Z=\{0\}$ and $(\beta_i)$ is a basis for $U$ then
$$\sum_i a_i\beta_i=0\implies a_i=0,\;\forall i$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the $\delta_i$'s were not a basis. Then we would have

$$a_1\delta_1+\cdots+a_k\delta_k=0$$

with $a_j\neq0$ for at least one $j$. But then you would have

$$a_1\beta_1+\cdots+a_k\beta_k=-a_1\gamma_1-\cdots-a_k\gamma_k$$

The left-hand side is a vector in $U$. The right hand side is a vector in $Z$. These two vectors are equal and it isn't the zero vector, since at least one $a_j\neq 0$ and the $\beta_i$'s constitute a basis for $U$. But this contradicts the fact that $V=U\oplus Z$.

Comment: There's a missed detail in your proof: you didn't use that $(\beta_i)$ is basis for $U$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane, isn't it sufficient to say that $a_1\beta_1+\cdots+a_k\beta_k\in U$?

Comment: No it isn't sufficient! You said that there's $a_j\ne0$ but this doesn't mean that $-a_1\gamma_1-\cdots-a_k\gamma_k\ne0$. Isn't it?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane, you're right; but let me know if I understood you: if at least one $a_j\neq 0$, then the left-hand side is $\neq 0$ \emph{once the $\beta_i$'s constitute a basis for $U$}

Comment: Yes this is the missed detail.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane, I edited the answer. Thank you for reading!